# How to generate custom session id with express-session?

Tags: node.js, session, express-session

I am using Redis as session store and I would also like to create custom session id with `express-session`. So far I achieved was creating session with constant string like this:

`redis configuration`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var compression = require('compression');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');

var app = express();
var client = redis.createClient();

// compress all requests
app.use(compression())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client}),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000
  },
  genid: function(req) {
    return "myApiKey";
  }
}));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/request_api', api);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

which creates keys in redis like below:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "sess:myApiKey"
```

However, I could not generate unique id with `uuid` as mentioned in doc here [session-store github](https://github.com/expressjs/session#genid). 
I have tried inserting session value in my index routes file (`routes/index.js`) like this

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.user = "12345";
  res.render('index', { title: 'MyApp' });
});
```

But could not read value inside `genid` function due to value `undefined`.
So, my question is:

Can I generate session id with `uuid` of any model like `user->uuid`? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question was responsed widely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875701/nodejs-express-global-unique-request-id/47261545#47261545

Comment: @DavidVicente That question/answer is not the same as the one asked here. This question refers to Session middleware and management, not request tracking

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this.

```
   var crypto = require('crypto');
   var uuid = require('node-uuid');
```

You need to require node-uuid and then in genid function

```
genid:function(req){
     return uuid.v1();
},
```

or to avoid id collision

```
 genid:function(req){
     return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuid.v1()).update(crypto.randomBytes(256)).digest("hex");
 },
```

You can access session id anywhere in the application by `req.sessionID`.

Comment: Hey! I stumbled upon this answer and got interested of why does the latter version of genid function create ids that avoid collision? Can you open that up a little? What's all that about? :)