# NodeJS Express - Global Unique Request Id

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

Is it possible to define a unique request Id that is included in each log statement without handing the logger to each method/function call?

Technologies in use: NodeJS, Express, Winston

Comment: If your open to using ES6, you might want to use `Symbol`

Comment: Would love to, but I am stuck on 0.10.13 for now

Comment: @MayorMonty how would that help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edited**

Finally, I have created a library that makes all the work. 
https://github.com/davicente/express-logger-unique-req-id

It is a wrapper of Winston library, so you can use it the same way.

Let me know if it helps you

---

We had this same problem in several projects, and I couldn't finde any complete solution for this question. We are using same technologies (Node.js, Express.js and Winston for logs)
I found a solution to this using a couple of libraries and wrapping Winston library:
- node-uuid for creating unique identificators for each request
- continuation-local-storage for sharing this IDs among different modules without sending req object in all the calls.

First I need to create and set the unique identificator with each request. I do it in the middleware:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var createNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace;
var myRequest = createNamespace('my request');

// Run the context for each request. Assign a unique identifier to each request
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    myRequest.run(function() {
        myRequest.set('reqId', uuid.v1());
        next();
    });
});
```

After that I had to wrap Winston library, recovering the id from the context and adding to the message of the log:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace;

// Wrap Winston logger to print reqId in each log
var formatMessage = function(message) {
    var myRequest = getNamespace('my request');
    message = myRequest && myRequest.get('reqId') ? message + " reqId: " + myRequest.get('reqId') : message;
    return message;
};

var logger = {
    log: function(level, message) {
        winstonLogger.log(level, formatMessage(message));
    },
    error: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.error(formatMessage(message));
    },
    warn: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.warn(formatMessage(message));
    },
    verbose: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.verbose(formatMessage(message));
    },
    info: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.info(formatMessage(message));
    },
    debug: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.debug(formatMessage(message));
    },
    silly: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.silly(formatMessage(message));
    }
};
module.exports = logger;
```

I think it was a little bit complex, so I decided to write it down in a post. You can get more information from there: [Express.js: Logging info with global unique request ID – Node.js](https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs)

I hope this helps with your problem.

Comment: this is for every request, i have read the blog it works fine for the every request it is comming, but if i have a function called test inside how can i set a trace id and use it in the logger.js so whenever the app starts the test function will execute and i can get a trace id

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand well what you say, can you specify a little bit more?

Comment: I have created a logger using winston , morgan and daily rotate file. The problem is that if i save the code only the log  folder and files are generated. if i try to hit the route the folder is not creating basically http req is taken care of morgan but eventhough i combined it it is not working

Comment: [`node-uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid) is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903188/306042) has a problem: the counter goes back to 0 every time the node process is restarted. Turns out there is fairly simple to work around. You simply add an express middleware that tags each request called with a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)  using the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package.

### For uuid Pre-2.0

```js
const uuid = require('uuid');
const app = express();
app.use(function (req, next) {
  req.id = uuid.v4();
  next();
});
```

### For uuid 3.0+

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const app = express();
app.use(function (req, next) {
  req.id = uuidv4();
  next();
});
```

Comment: this approach would move the problem from handing the logger down to each object to handing the request down to each object.

Comment: Is the generated req.id really unique? Or you can get 2 sessions with the same id if the process is restarted? As I saw in the uuid docs, it doesn't use persistent storage.

Comment: Deep requires `require('uuid/v4')` are deprecated according to the [uuid readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning of your request handling add something like the following (or put it in its own file):

```
var makeID = (function() {
  var index = 0;
  return function() {
   return index++;
  }
})();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.id = makeID()
  next()
})
```

This will give every request a unique (sequential) id. **Do not allow people to identify themselves with it, only use it internally!**

When logging in Winston, you can enter metadata, to be displayed after the message (in the form `${name}=${value}`), which looks like this

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  winston.log('info', 'Test Log Message', { id: req.id });
  res.end("Done.")
});
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That is the solution that is currently implemented, but the request Id is not variable within other modules/functions/methods without modifying every related definition to include the request Id or logger.

Comment: Couldn't you just use cookies, then?

Comment: Would one not need req to gain access to z cookies?

Comment: Yeah, or you could just save the all the open connections' `req` and `res` in some sort of global object

Comment: @smokedice did you end up finding a way to log request id through out your service without passing down the requestId or logger to other modules??? im looking for a way to do that right now, can't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: @Eatdoku afraid not :(

Comment: btw, index goes back to 0 every time you restart this node process, this doesn't seem like a good long term solution

Comment: Please, @smokedice  check my answer, I finally got it after a lot of researchs.
I hope my work helps you