# Express.js unique var per request outside routing

Tags: node.js, express

In my express application I have a module called helpers thats is required in almost all my routes and modules. This module has a logger method that logs to fluentd (but that's unimportant). While building the data to log I'd like to add a unique identifier of the request, so that all the logs written for the same request have the same unique ID. Using a global var in the app entry point app.use doesn't work because this var would be overwritten every time a new request hits, so the global uuid will change would obviously change in case of high load or long running tasks. The res.locals is not available outside routing, so I can't use it for this matter. Is there a way to create a var that would be unique per request and available in every module or maybe a way to access the res.locals data outside routing? Thank you

EDIT

Maybe an example will help understand better the question.
Suppose I have a module called helpers.js like this:

```
let helpers = {};
helpers.log = (logData, logName) => {
    fluentLogger.emit('', {
        name: logName,
        //uuid: the needed uuid,
        message: logData
    });
}
module.exports = helpers;
```

Now obviously I can do this in my app.js entry point:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.uuid = uuid.v4();
    next();
});
```

and then in every loaded middleware module that requires helpers(adding a new param to the helpers.log method):

```
const helpers = require('helpers');
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    helpers.log('my log message', 'myLogName', res.locals.uuid);
    next();
});
```

and this will normally work. But suppose a big or middle size project where there are hundreds of custom modules and models (not middlewares) and a module may require other modules that require other modules that require finally the helpers module. In this case I should pass the res.locals.uuid as a parameter to every method of every method so that I have it available in the logger method. Not a very good idea. Suppose I have a new module called dbmodel.js that is required in a middleware function:

```
const helpers = require('helpers');
let dbmodel = {};
dbmodel.getSomeData = (someParam) => {
    //some logic
    helpers.log('my log message', 'myLogName');
}
module.exports = dbmodel;
```

The dbmodel has no idea about the res.locals data if I don't pass it from the middleware, so the helpers.log method will also have no idea about this.

In PHP one would normally write a GLOBAL var in the application's entry point so a hypothetical logger function would have access to this global on every method request from whichever class of the application.

Hope this explanation will help :) Thank you

EDIT 2

The solution for this kind of problems is [CLS](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage). Thanks to @robertklep for the hint. A good slideshare explaining exactly the same problem (logger with unique ID) and explaining the CLS solutions can be found here: https://www.slideshare.net/isharabash/cls-and-asynclistener

Comment: What do you mean with "The res.locals is not available outside routing" ? What prevents you to use in in the handling of the request ?

Comment: To the editor: please don't abuse code formatting. It's reserved to code.

Comment: You can add a new property to the request object from a middleware function (e.g. `req.requestId = uuidv4()`)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The helpers module is not a middleware, it's just a module with helper functions that is required everywhere, in middlewares, other modules and db models for example. Maybe I'm missing something but simple modules, not middlewares have no access to the request data (either req or res). I'm using res.locals in my project to pass data across middlewares, but I can access this vars only inside a middleware. Am I missing something?

Comment: A global in PHP is available during the lifetime _of the request_, a global in JS is available during the lifetime _of the application_. There isn't a straight solution for Node that would mimick what you'd do in PHP. I know some people like using [CLS](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage), but I've never used it.

Comment: @robertklep yes and this is the reason I was asking for help, because I'm out of ideas. I had a quick look at the CLS module and it seems interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @robertklep just wanted to thank you, the module works great and  did the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I answered a very similar question here which will solve this problem.
I used to solve the problem the libraries node-uuid and continuation-local-storage. Take a look to the answer of this question and see if it helps:

[NodeJS Express - Global Unique Request Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875701/nodejs-express-global-unique-request-id)

And you want a bigger explanation, take a look here:

[Express.js: Logging info with global unique request ID – Node.js](https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so by one method .
Every request comes to his routes pass that request inside the middleware.
Suppose you have

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public + "index.html"));
 });
```

a request.

Place Middleware in it .and edit req field coming , in this way you will get the unique variable values  for each request

check out this .
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Like this

```
var requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now()
  next()
}

app.use(requestTime)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var responseText = 'Hello World!<br>'
  responseText += '<small>Requested at: ' + req.requestTime + '</small>'
  res.send(responseText)
})
```

**Here  req.requestTime is unique for each request.**

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thanks for you help. Please see my comment above.